# Getting an error when creating a WebBrowser in a new thread vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a new webbrowser with a new thread, but when I try to run the program I'm always getting the following error:

[image]
Can someone help me fix this error please? Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    Dim curFile1 As String = TextBox4.Text
    If (File.Exists(curFile1)) Then
        MsgBox("Ok")
    Else
        MsgBox("Please a User Agent file", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim curFile2 As String = TextBox1.Text
    If (File.Exists(curFile2)) Then
        MsgBox("Ok")
    Else
        MsgBox("Please a IP file", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        ' Open the file using a stream reader.
        Using sr As New StreamReader(curFile2)
            ' Read the stream to a string and write the string to the console.
            ip_text = File.ReadAllLines(curFile2)
        End Using
    Catch er As Exception
        MsgBox("The file could not be read: IP", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Exit Sub
    End Try


    Try
        ' Open the file using a stream reader.
        Using sr2 As New StreamReader(curFile1)
            ' Read the stream to a string and write the string to the console.
            user_text = File.ReadAllLines(curFile1)
        End Using
    Catch er As Exception
        MsgBox("The file could not be read: User Agent", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Exit Sub
    End Try


    nr = 0
    For Each ip As String In ip_text

        MsgBox(ip)

        trd = New Thread(AddressOf make_it)
        trd.IsBackground = True
        trd.Start()

        nr = nr + 1
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub make_it()
    Dim decible = New WebBrowser()
    web_panel.Controls.Add(decible)

    decible.Name = "browser" & nr
    Dim RandomIpAddress As String = user_text(GetRandom(user_text.Length))
    MsgBox(RandomIpAddress)

    ChangeUserAgent(RandomIpAddress)
    decible.Navigate("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/")

End Sub
```

Help is greatly appreciated, stuck on this error for days now.

Comment: Images of error text are generally a bad idea since people are going to want to do searches on the error text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because the new thread(s) that you create are generally in a so called *Multithreaded Apartment* (MTA). According to the error the `WebBrowser` control can only be created on a thread that is in a *Single-threaded Apartment* (STA, an example being the UI thread).

Changing your thread's apartment is not recommended because it must be MTA in order to be multithreaded alongside of the UI thread.

This leaves you with pretty much only one option: create ***and modify*** the control on the UI thread only, and do the other heavy lifting in your new thread.

I would create the control on the UI thread, and in the end of the thread I would perform invocation to run the navigating code.

### Solution for .NET Framework 4.0 or higher:

**In your loop:**

```
Dim decible = New WebBrowser()
decible.Name = "browser" & nr
web_panel.Controls.Add(decible)

trd = New Thread(AddressOf make_it)
trd.IsBackground = True
trd.Start(decible) 'Passing the web browser as a parameter.
```

**The `make_it` method:**

```
Private Sub make_it(ByVal decible As WebBrowser)
    Dim RandomIpAddress As String = user_text(GetRandom(user_text.Length))
    MsgBox(RandomIpAddress)

    ChangeUserAgent(RandomIpAddress)

    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() decible.Navigate("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/"))
    Else
        decible.Navigate("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/")
    End If

End Sub
```

---

### Solution for .NET Framework 3.5 or lower:

**In your loop (this is the same as above):**

```
Dim decible = New WebBrowser()
decible.Name = "browser" & nr
web_panel.Controls.Add(decible)

trd = New Thread(AddressOf make_it)
trd.IsBackground = True
trd.Start(decible) 'Passing the web browser as a parameter.
```

**The `make_it` method:**

```
Private Sub make_it(ByVal decible As WebBrowser)
    Dim RandomIpAddress As String = user_text(GetRandom(user_text.Length))
    MsgBox(RandomIpAddress)

    ChangeUserAgent(RandomIpAddress)

    NavigateWebBrowser(decible, "http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/")

End Sub

Delegate Sub NavigateDelegate(ByVal Browser As WebBrowser, ByVal Url As String)

Private Sub NavigateWebBrowser(ByVal Browser As WebBrowser, ByVal Url As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(New NavigateDelegate(AddressOf NavigateWebBrowser), Browser, Url)
    Else
        Browser.Navigate(Url)
    End If
End Sub
```